# Derived set of uncountable sets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ be an uncountable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $S'\cap S=\emptyset $ where $S'$ is the derived set of $S$. Is such a set possible? If not why?

Answer (score 2):

No, every uncountable subset $S$ of $\Bbb R$ has an accumulation point among its points:

Let $B_n, n \in \Bbb N$ be a countable base for $\Bbb R$ (e.g. the rational open intervals), and suppose that $S \subseteq \Bbb R$ is such that $S' \cap S = \emptyset$. The latter implies that for each $x \in S$ there is some $n(x) \in \Bbb N$ so that $x \in B_{n(x)}$ and $B_{n(x)} \cap S = \{x\}$ (to witness that this $x \in S$ is not in $S'$, and using that the $B_n$ form a base for the topology).

It is clear that $x \to n(x)$ is an injection so that $S$ is at most countable.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you simplify this a little bit more?

Comment: @DenisJames this is already quite simple. What is your issue?

Comment: countable base? rational open interval? Im not a topology student which is why im unaware of these concepts. It would be helpful if you literally spoon-feed it to me. sorry

Comment: @DenisJames all open intervals $(p,q)$ with $p,q \in \Bbb Q$.